# how to write vbscript oracle connection string

Tags: vbscript, ado.net, database-connection, connection-string, oracle-sqldeveloper

> **How to write connection string for vbscript and oracle connection?**

connstr = "Provider=SQLNCLI;Data Source=server\instance;User ID=username; 
          Password=password;Initial Catalog=database_name;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the OraOLEDB driver. [More info](https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-provider-for-ole-db-oraoledb/)

```
Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=MyOracleDB;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Or the Microsoft driver. [More info](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-oracle-msdaora/)

```
Provider=msdaora;Data Source=MyOracleDB;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```